# basic jQuery plugin template

Tags: javascript, jquery, template, plugin

I would like to know if I'm writing a plugin for jquery correctly. I followed the [official guide](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) and also added some tweaks that I've found from various sources over time.

While this works perfectly, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

This is the sample:

```
(function($)
{
    var plugin = "my_plugin_name";
    var methods = {
        init : function(user_settings)
        {
            return this.each(function(index)
            {
                if(!$(this).hasClass("plugin_class"))
                {
                    $(this).addClass("plugin_class");

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var data = $this.data(plugin);

                    if(!data)
                    {
                        var default_settings = {
                            optionA: "abc",
                            optionB: 123,
                            optionB: true
                        };

                        if(user_settings)
                        {
                            $.extend(true, default_settings, user_settings);
                        }

                        $this.data(plugin,
                        {
                            "settings": default_settings
                        });
                    }

                    privateMethod($this);
                }
           });
        },
        exposedMethodX : function(value) //$(selector).my_plugin_name("exposedMethodX", true)
        {
            console.log(value)
        }
    };

    $.fn[plugin] = function(method)
    {
        if(methods[method])
        {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if(typeof method === "object" || !method)
        {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Method " +  method + " does not exist");
        }
    };

    function privateMethod(obj)
    {
        console.log(obj.data(plugin).settings);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ahoy! Would you have any sample usage for this template you could add to the post?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ This is just a sample. Only a general structure. `$(selector).my_plugin_name()` will work, also `$(selector).my_plugin_name("exposedMethodX", 123)`

Comment: When adding more context please [edit] instead of doing so in a comment

Comment: There [exists a GitHub repository with several examples of jQuery plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns), if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

In general the template looks like a good start. I noticed that the code appears to resemble the format advised in [PHP-Fig's PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), namely "*The opening brace MUST go on its own line*"<sup>[1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#43-methods)</sup> for functions and methods plus control structures like `if` and `else` blocks. Most of the Javascript style guides I have seen call for curly braces to exist on the same line of the block they are opening. Personally I don't even agree with this in PHP, let alone Javascript, however if that is your personal preference then keep it consistent.

---

Inside the `init` method, there is an iterator:

> ```
> return this.each(function(index)
> {
>     if(!$(this).hasClass("plugin_class"))
>     {
>         $(this).addClass("plugin_class");
>
>        var $this = $(this);
> ```

The reference `var $this = $(this);` could be stored before the check of the class name and/or class name addition in order to reduce DOM queries.

Also, the name `$this` could be more descriptive - at least something like `$element` or `$elem` (as shown in the example under [*Provide Public Access to Secondary Functions as Applicable*](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/#provide-public-access-to-secondary-functions-as-applicable) from the [Advanced Plugin Concepts](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/)).

### Addressing Your Additional question

You asked in a comment:

> *what about the `$.fn[plugin]` part? I'm not sure about the first if statement. could that function be refactored and improved?*

It is possible that [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) could potentially be used to simplify the call, though given that [current jQuery browser support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) includes IE 9+ it may not be wise to utilize ES-6 features.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. what about the `$.fn[plugin]` part? I'm not sure about the first if statement. could that function be refactored and improved?

Comment: I expanded my answer to address your question

Answer (score 2):

From a short review;

- Please follow the lowerCamelCase naming convention, `user_settings` -> `userSettings`
- In production code, never use `console.log` or `alert`
- You set `optionB` twice

  ```
          var default_settings = {
              optionA: "abc",
              optionB: 123,
              optionB: true
          };
  ```
- The cyclomatic complexity would be lower if you exit immediately after the `hasClass` check:

  ```
          if($(this).hasClass("plugin_class")){
              return;
          }
  ```
- You could even consider using `filter` on `hasClass` instead of checking for `each`
- `"plugin_class"` should be a constant right under `var plugin`
- The following

  ```
          if(user_settings)
          {
              $.extend(true, default_settings, user_settings);
          }
  ```

  could be written as

  ```
          $.extend(true, user_settings || default_settings);
  ```